# How to list orders in sql query?

Tags: jquery, sql, northwind

I'm trying to get a list of my orders (employee name, order date, customer) using the northwind database:

[northwind database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkdDy.png)

Can you see what is wrong with my query?

```
select 
    e.FirstName as Name, e.LastName as Lastname, 
    o.OrderDate as Date, s.CompanyName as Customer
from 
    Emplyees e 
join 
    Orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
```

Comment: What is `s.CompanyName`?

Comment: What's the [full] error? And yeah, there's no table alias `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `from Emplyees`, where Employees is missing the `o`. Also, as commented by @GordonLinoff, there is an issue with `s.CompanyName`, as there is no table alias called `s` in your query.

By looking at your database schema, I assume that you are looking for the `CompanyName` field that comes from table `Customers`, as you aliased that column `Customer` (could as well be `Shippers.CompanyName`, but looks less likely).

If so, you want to add another `JOIN` in your query to include table `Customers` (aliased as `c`) :

```
select 
    e.FirstName, 
    e.LastName,
    o.OrderDate as Date, 
    c.CompanyName as CustomerCompany
from
    Employees e 
    join Orders    o on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    join Customers c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

NB : aliasing an output column with the same name is redundant, I removed that.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the typo?..."Emplyees"?

Answer (score 0):

From where do you get s.CompanyName if your join does not use it? Remove it and test your query again. If it does not solve your problem check also the typo on Emplyee table.